# SQL Chinook Database SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL, my project was sent back saying the query has errors, I don't see errors when I run it. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Invoice.Invoiceid, Invoice.Customerid, Invoice.InvoiceDate, Invoice.BillingCountry, Invoice.Total AS “Total Spent”
FROM Invoice
JOIN Customer
ON Invoice.Customerid=Customer.Customerid
JOIN InvoiceLine
ON InvoiceLine.InvoiceLineid=Invoice.Invocieid
WHERE total BETWEEN 10.00 AND 50.00
ORDER BY InvoiceDate
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: The quoting in `“Total Spent”` is *a little* off (you haven't written thst in Word or similar by any chance?). Use simple "unified" double quotes (`"`) instead of opening an closing ones. But other than that it seems syntactically OK. But what is the query actually supposed to do? And What are your table definitions (please provide DDL). Maybe it semantically wrong, but without further information, that's hard to judge.

Comment: That was written as a Word DOC. Thank you for responding.

Comment: The query was to show who was the top buyer of tracks in the data base